# Wicket Ajax with upload field -  in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, wicket

1. I have an upload field in a wicket form.
2. I use AjaxFormSubmitBehavior with the event "onchange" so when the user just select a file and I already do upload and display the image in a little panel beside.
3. It's working fine in Firefox & Chrome but not in IE (IE8 / IE9). In IE when the user selects a file:

   a. A new window with the response code (in a tag called "ajax-response") is opened.

   b. The Wicket Ajax Debug box says: "ERROR: Error parsing response".
4. Note that other Ajax calls in this application are working well in IE too.
5. I'm attaching the relevant piece of code.  Thanks in advance, David

private FileUploadField file;

```
        FileUploadField fuf = new FileUploadField("file");

        AjaxFormSubmitBehavior ajaxFormSubmitBehavior = new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior("onchange") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                MlCmpBlob img = handleUpload();

                ImageDisplayPanel imageDisplayPanelTmp = new ImageDisplayPanel("uploadImgDisplay", new Model<MlCmpBlob>(img));
                imageDisplayPanel.replaceWith(imageDisplayPanelTmp);
                imageDisplayPanel = imageDisplayPanelTmp;
                target.add(imageDisplayPanel);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                target.add(wizardFormFeedback);
            }
        };
        ajaxFormSubmitBehavior.setDefaultProcessing(false);
        fuf.add(ajaxFormSubmitBehavior);
        add(file = fuf);
```

Comment: Which Wicket version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Wicket version 6.0.0-beta2

Comment: Actually it's seems like a problem with the Ajax upload of 6.0.0-beta2 and 6.0.0-beta3, since I can see the problem in the wicket-examples of this version.      (I took the wicket-examples from the wicket 6.0.0-beta3. download folder,  and I created it as a java project. My purpose was to check if this is only my application problem or a real problem.
And actually I saw that the problem exists also in the Ajax upload file of wicket-examples of version 6.0.0-beta3. )
I sent this issue to the users mailing list of wicket.